# Javascript Passport - Always gets "Unauthorized"

Tags: express, passport.js

I've creating a website and I'm currently working on the login details.

I'm using the Passport plugin for a fullstack app, but everytime I try to login i get "Unauthorized" no matter what I do.

**LOGIN CONTROLLER**

```
$scope.login = function(form) {
  $scope.submitted = true;

  if(form.$valid) {
    Auth.login({
      email: $scope.user.email,
      password: $scope.user.password,
    })
    .then( function() {
      // Logged in, redirect to home
      $location.path('/');
    })
    .catch( function(err) {
      $scope.errors.other = err.message;
      console.log(err);
    });
  }
};
```

**AUTH SERVICE**

```
login: function(user, callback) {
    var cb = callback || angular.noop;
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    $http.post('/auth/local', {
      email: user.email,
      password: user.password
    }).
    success(function(data) {
      $cookieStore.put('token', data.token);
      currentUser = User.get();
      deferred.resolve(data);
      return cb();
    }).
    error(function(err) {
      this.logout();
      deferred.reject(err);
      return cb(err);
    }.bind(this));

    return deferred.promise;
  },
```

**SERVERSIDE INDEX.JS**

```
'use strict';

var express = require('express');
var passport = require('passport');
var auth = require('../auth.service');

var router = express.Router();

router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user, info) {
    var error = err || info;
    if (error) return res.json(401, error);
    if (!user) return res.json(404, {message: 'Something went wrong, please try again.'});

    var token = auth.signToken(user._id, user.role);
    res.json({token: token});
  })(req, res, next)
});

module.exports = router;
```

*I'm relatively new with the passport plugin, so I don't know where to find the error. Tell me if you need more code.*

This is the message I get from the console:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401     (Unauthorized) angular.js:9866 
GET http://localhost:9000/api/users/me 401 (Unauthorized)
```

Comment: Need more code :) Need to see your call to `passport.use`.

Comment: I was missing some code in my project which caused the problem

Answer (score -1):

**Found the problem**

I was missing some code. I don't know why but I did. Problem has been solved.

**The code that was missing in app.js:**

```
.factory('authInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, $cookieStore, $location) {
return {
  // Add authorization token to headers
  request: function (config) {
    config.headers = config.headers || {};
    if ($cookieStore.get('token')) {
      config.headers.Authorization = 'Bearer ' + $cookieStore.get('token');
    }
    return config;
  },

  // Intercept 401s and redirect you to login
  responseError: function(response) {
    if(response.status === 401) {
      $location.path('/login');
      // remove any stale tokens
      $cookieStore.remove('token');
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
    else {
      return $q.reject(response);
    }
  }
};
})

.run(function ($rootScope, $location, Auth) {
    // Redirect to login if route requires auth and you're not logged in
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, next) {
      Auth.isLoggedInAsync(function(loggedIn) {
        if (next.authenticate && !loggedIn) {
          $location.path('/login');
        }
      });
    });
});
```

Comment: Glad you managed to solve your problem! In the interest of other SO users who might see this show up in search results, it would be nice to either delete this question outright or at least show what you did to fix the problem.